# What salvages into what?

Tags: diablo-iii

What items turn into what when you salvage them?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As of Patch 2.0, all items level 1-60 now salvage into Common Debris (for white and grey items), Exquisite Essences (for blue items), Iridescent Tears (for yellow items), or Fiery Brimstones (for legendary items).  Any of the old crafting items you had were converted into their equivalent new item.

Items from level 61-70 turn into Reusable Parts, Arcane Dust, Veiled Crystals, and Forgotten Souls for white, blue, yellow, and legendary items, respectively.

Comment: The last patch has changed this again - the low level stuff seems to have been removed completely. Everything salvages into the high level materials now.

Answer (score 2):

Additional information on the RoS materials. While materials from 1-60 items are not account bound, RoS materials from 61-70 *are* account bound.

The most common way these are used is in crafting or enchanting, mostly the latter.

- Reusable Parts: Comes from salvaging gray or white items. Yields 7-10 per item and stacks to 1000.
- Arcane Dust: Comes from salvaging blue items. Yields 1-4 per item and stacks to 1000.
- Veiled Crystal: Comes from salvaging yellow items. Yields 1 per item and stacks to 1000.
- Forgotten Soul: Comes from salvaging legendary or set items. Yields 1 per item and stacks to 1000.

As of the most recent patch 2.1 all blue (magic), yellow (rare), and white/gray (normal) items may each be salvaged as a group in your current inventory at the blacksmith.

> "New buttons have been added to salvage all normal, magic, or rare quality items in your inventory at once" -**[Patch 2.1<sup>diablowiki</sup>](http://www.diablowiki.net/Patch_2.1#CRAFTING)**