# What type of items drop "Fiery Brimstone"?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find items with the right level to salvage particular ingredients?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68909/how-do-i-find-items-with-the-right-level-to-salvage-particular-ingredients)

I was wondering what type of items the fiery brimstone drops from and what the drop rate is. And is it possible to get the achievement for getting fiery brimstone by just buying it from the AH?

Comment: Nobody mention Fiery Brimstone in the other thread.

Comment: Michel specifically includes Fiery Brimstone in his question, under Inferno materials.

Comment: There are no answers with it.

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: Level 60 magic items of all types now show a 0% chance to drop a Fiery Brimstone:

- http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/glorious-doom-treads

Any level 60 legendary item will salvage to a Fiery Brimstone.  Crafted rares show a 0.1% chance of yielding Fiery Brimstone:

- http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/exalted-heaven-strand

The rule is likely this:

- Inferno tier rare items have 0.1% chance to salvage to Fiery Brimstone
- Inferno tier set and legendary items always salvage to one Fiery Brimstone
- Magic items no longer yield Fiery Brimstone

Comment: I believe this answer is now out of date.  It seems the drop rate for jewelry is now zero for fiery brimstone.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find any official post, but the drop rates of Fiery Brimstones supposedly got stealth nerfed.

It seems you can only get it from iLvl61+ rares with a drop chance of 0.1% that is 1 in 1000 and from legendary and set items.

This is why the Essence prices went down while the Fiery Brimstone prices constantly rise in the AH.

Before the nerf the drop chances were 0.8% from Amulets with iLvl61+. This is why there was a huge demand for Essences, as the recipes required quite a few of those.

Here are some unofficial posts:

- [Fiery Brimstone](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/fiery-brimstone)
- [Bnet Thread](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5978370493)